# Reference to a non-shared member requires an object reference"

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am working on a restaurant system .when a customer open the website the main page will display the time and whether it is breakfast lunch or dinner depending on the time . But it keep giving me this message  under the welcomelabel.text in the vb code  .'welcomeLabel' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.

the vb code :

```
Partial Class _Default
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Protected Sub Page_Init(ByVal sender As Object, _
    ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

        Dim time As Date
        Dim CurrHour As Double

        time = DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss")
        CurrHour = time.ToString("hh")


        If CurrHour = 10 Or CurrHour = 11 Then
            Welcomeabel.Text = time
           WelcomeLabel.ForeColor = Drawing.Color.White
           WelcomeLabel.Font.Size = "20"
            WelcomeLabel.BackColor = Drawing.Color.Black

        ElseIf CurrHour = 12 Or CurrHour = 1 Or CurrHour = 2 Or CurrHour = 3 Or CurrHour = 4 Or CurrHour = 5 Then
            label.Text = "Welcome dears you can enjoy ordering our meals!!It is your lUNCH Now " + time
            WelcomeLabel.ForeColor = Drawing.Color.White
           WelcomeLabel.Font.Size = "20"
            WelcomeLabel.BackColor = Drawing.Color.Black

        ElseIf CurrHour = 6 Or CurrHour = 7 Then
            label.Text = "Welcome dears you can enjoy ordering our meals!!come on and have a quick meal " + time
            WelcomeLabel.ForeColor = Drawing.Color.White
            WelcomeLabel.Font.Size = "20"
            WelcomeLabel.BackColor = Drawing.Color.Black

        ElseIf CurrHour = 8 Or CurrHour = 9 Then
            label.Text = "Welcome dears you can enjoy ordering our meals!!It is your Dinner Now " + time
           WelcomeLabel.ForeColor = Drawing.Color.White
           WelcomeLabel.Font.Size = "20"
            WelcomeLabel.BackColor = Drawing.Color.Black


        End If
    End Sub

End Class
```

the asp code : where the label id is welcomeLabel , so whats going wrong with the code???

```
<div style="margin-left: 16px"> 
            <asp:Label ID="welcomelabel" runat="server" BackColor="Black" 
          EnableViewState="False" Font-Size="XX-Large"            
        ForeColor="Yellow"></asp:Label>   <br /><br /><br />
  </div>
```

Comment: Where you able to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2):

It seems you have a naming conflict.  VB.Net is not a case sensitive language, rename the id to something other than label and then access it by ID, alternately you can specifify the Me.label.Text to assuage the compiler

Answer (score 1):

VB is not case sensitive.  You have called your Label "label", which is causing conflicts.  The line

```
 label.Text = "Some Text"
```

for example, is interpreted as referencing the class `Label` rather than the instance `label` on your page.  The solution is simple - don't use class names for variables.  Call your label something else (ie : "welcomeLabel", etc).